# Custom view controller for Settings bundle?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have an application with a settings view that loads settings dynamically from a remote server. It's working fine.

I want to also make these available in iPhone Settings, but the Settings bundle seems to be limited to simple key-values loaded and saved to the local NSUserDefaults. Is there a way to specify a custom view for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Setting bundles are based on plist files and do not contain any code. You cannot perform any kind of calculation in the Settings app. You have build your own settings UI and put it in your app.

Apple does use more complex settings bundles which perform code, but apps in the App Store cannot do that.