# Selecting Multi-Value Element in settings bundle not returning to previous page

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, application-settings

My settings bundle specifies a Multi-Value element of type PSMultiValueSpecifier exactly as [described by Apple](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/PreferenceSettings/Conceptual/SettingsApplicationSchemaReference/Articles/PSMultiValueSpecifier.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007016-SW1).

I have all the required Keys entered, as well as the Titles array matching the values array in size. The default value is an integer, and matches a value in the values array (so no problems there).

My issue is a usability one - Apple states:

> Upon selecting a value, the user is returned to the previous page, and
>   the selected value is displayed in the preference row.

This is what happens across many of the built in settings preferences.

However, when tapping an element in my settings bundle, it selects the value but does not return back. Is there a key I'm missing?

I am running iOS 4.02

Comment: You might want to provide a text dump of your settings bundle. As you state your question, it's hard to guess what's happening.

Comment: Seems to be working in iOS 4.2. You did press the "back" button on the left of the navigation control after selecting the row, right?

Comment: I can select the row fine, to clarify, the problem I am having is that I want it to pop the view controller as soon as the row is selected, not have to select, then click the back button on the navigation controller.

Comment: I didn't happen to see an instance like that on my settings. Can you give an example where in Apple's settings it did that?

Comment: BTW, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/951051/custom-view-controller-for-settings-bundle/951134#951134 says "Apple does use more complex settings bundles which perform code, but apps in the App Store cannot do that." so maybe Apple has done so where you found it, but it doesn't appear available to 3rd party developers.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behaviour. And a quick survey of installed apps shows the same behaviour everywhere else, too. I think the documentation is wrong (or, at least, describes behaviour that doesn't exist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this question to close it after over 2 years. 
It seems that Apple's documentation is (still) incorrect. The transition to the previous view controller will not occur on value selection.