# Is there a way to create custom settings bundle?

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi

I am looking a way to create a custom view and show it in Settings.

I am aware that public API doesn't allow to do this and it will be rejected by AppStore (if it's possible). I am working on enterprise app, so it's not a concern.
[Custom view controller for Settings bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951051/custom-view-controller-for-settings-bundle)

My question is whether there are some private API or private plist configuration which could be used to create a custom settings bundle view? I am looking for something which will work on jailed (non jailbroken devices).

**Update 1**

I think some customization is possible. I look at my iPad and see reasonable complex settings for Twitter and Facebook. Both of them have "Install", "Sign In", "Create New Account" buttons with some functionality. It looks like quite a lot of preinstalled settings bundles goes beyond simple configuration.

**Update 2**

It looks like Twitter and Facebook has standalone bundle. It could be located here /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/System/Library/PreferenceBundles/TwitterSettings.bundle/

I am still unsure whether there is some special support in Settings app which will allow to Twitter and Facebook to have more complex settings or whether 3rd party custom view in settings is possible, but just not documented.

Comment: Twitter and Facebook are built into iOS as of 6, I doubt this is a setting that is available to anyone.

Comment: Please read my update 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible (to my knowledge) without jailbreaking.  The options that show up in the settings correspond to the value type that you set for the variable being modified (i.e. bools are switches, etc).  To get access to the Settings you'd need a jailbroken access.

Comment: Please take a look on update to my question. I have a feeling that some customization is possible.

Comment: You are right in your update, but Twitter and Facebook both have OS support.  The views for their settings panel are defined by the OS and not by their apps (not that those are still available even when the apps aren't installed).

Comment: That's fine, but you're still at a stand still.  If the ability isn't documented then that means that the API isn't exposed.  If it's not exposed then you can't do it without jailbreaking.

Comment: That's not true. There is a whole bunch of undocumented API's, Info.plist entries for iOS (called private API's). They can be successfully used on non jailbroken devices. However, application with usage of such API won't be allowed to AppStore. Usually they are used for enterprise apps or for apps for your own usage (which won't be distributed).

Comment: That's true, but undocumented API's are unsupported API's (to the public).  That means that if they change something they don't have to notify you.  Have fun with that.

Comment: It looks like Preferences applicataton differentiate how it loads build-in and 3rd party preferences bundle. I looked at it a little bit in disassembler. So, I believe you are right.